scp and mv to copy file to a server and a folder in multiple sessions
I am having an issue with missing files while copying and moving them. To give a bit of background,
I have a crontab job that starts when file arrives into a communication server. I need these files in another server, so I am copying to the server before processing those file.
#!/bin/bash
######
#####

### Set initial time of file
LTIME=`stat -c %Z /mnt/deliverFiles/*.txt`

while true    
do
   ATIME=`stat -c %Z /mnt/deliverFiles/*.txt`

   if [[ "$ATIME" != "$LTIME" ]]
   then    
       scp -p /mnt/deliverFiles/*.txt server:/home/files/
       mv /mnt/deliverFiles/*.txt /home/files/
                
echo "Fertig."
LTIME=$ATIME
   fi
   sleep 5
done

I don't receive all the files into server. can anyone help here with a better Idea?

Did you check whether the script produces error messager? For debugging, I would put as first command set -x (this not only gives you a trace of what happens, you also can be sure that now there is something on stderr), and - for the safe side - do a echo $PATH and an echo $BASH_VERSION and the command id (to see which user the script is executed under). If it's still not clear what's going on, let us see the output.

stat -c %Z /mnt/deliverFiles/*.txt stat does not work with wildcard expansion of multiple file names.

Another old school solution is to have the producing side send a "flag" file AFTER the main file has been sent. Then you watch for that file to appear. The flag file could also include details of the sent file, record count, timestamp of run, character count that you could use in data verification. Good luck

You may want to work with inotify (install inotify-tools).
#!/usr/bin/env sh

deliverFiles=/mnt/deliverFiles
remotePath=server:/home/files
transferredPath=/home/files

# Monitor file close write in directory
inotifywait --monitor --format '%w%f' --event close_write "$deliverFiles/" |
{
  # Read the modified file path returned by inotifywait monitoring
  while read -r srcPath
  do
    if
      scp -p -- "$srcPath" "$remotePath/" &&
      mv -- "$srcPath" "$transferredPath"
    then
      printf 'Transferred and moved %s\n' "$srcPath"
    else
      printf 'An error occurred while transferring %s\n' "$srcPath" >&2
    fi
  done
}

This script will keep waiting for files to be added/modified in the designated path, then perform the scp and move as desired. But this is not appropriate for a cron task. This is a script to run as a daemon.
